# Get the email address of push notification received through Outlook Webhook

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, webhooks, subscription

I have created a subscription for multiple accounts of Outlook. I recieve a notification every time  a new email is recieved in the inbox. How do i get the email Address for which the push notification was meant to be.

The payload has the following format:

```
`array (
  0 =>
  (object) array(
     'subscriptionId' => '',
     'subscriptionExpirationDateTime' => '',
     'changeType' => 'updated',
     'resource' => '',
     'resourceData' =>
    (object) array(
       '@odata.type' => '#Microsoft.Graph.Message',
       '@odata.id' => '',
       '@odata.etag' => '',
       'id' => '',
    ),
     'clientState' => NULL,
     'tenantId' => '',
  ),
)`
```

This is the structure of the response of Outlook push notification. I want to get the email address for which this notification was sent.
Thank you a lot.

I tried to get the values in the resourceData and decode them but i am clueless as to how to get the email address.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the documentation to include resource data is only available in the beta endpoint:

[image]

Use Receive notifications with resource data (preview) to also include the email and details of it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-change-notifications-overview?tabs=http#receive-notifications-with-resource-data-preview

Hope this helps